# Protractor Failed:Script timeout if I have 20+ tests in one JS file

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor

```
Failed: chrome not reachable
(Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

If the "it" statement is over 20 in one JS file, I am getting such an error. I was thinking of adding JasmineNodeOpt might work, but it ended up giving me the same error. What else can I try here?

Answer (score 0):

Update: 
1)Set your selenium promise manager to be False.

```
exports.config = {

  ...
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  ...

};
```

2) Put async/await to handle the waits: you can find an example here: https://github.com/BhattcharyaCodes/google_search_automation This way, if there is a promise which is unhandled previously, will not not be a miscreant leading to this error.

3) Distribute your test on spec level. So having multiple spec files you can run your tests on different instances. Try running your tests in parallel, instead of 1 browser instance that way you can optimize your time. To do this, you can add,

```
// Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'maxInstances': 5,
    'browserName': 'chrome',

  },
```

to your `protractor_configuration_file.js`.

MaxInstances: It translates to the number of instances of same version of browser can run over the Remote System, where the test scripts from your spec executes.

Additionally, you mentioned about increasing the value "JasmineNodeOpt", but for obvious reasons this is not a scalable option beyond a set threshold, hence we increase the instances to reduce the overall time.